# Approximation of continuous projections on a manifold by smooth idempotents

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras

Every continuous vector bundle on a closed smooth manifold $M$ has a smooth structure. On the other hand, every vector bundle $E$ is the image of a trivial bundle $M\times\mathbb{C}^n$ under some projection $p$ in a matrix algebra $M_n(C(M))$. I am wondering if it possible to approximate this projection by a smooth idempotent, call it $e$, and whether it is possible to preserve certain properties of $p$.

More precisely:

**Question 1:** Take any $\varepsilon>0$. Does there exist an idempotent $e\in M_n(C^\infty(M))$ such that $\|p(x)-e(x)\|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in M$?

**Question 2:** Suppose $p$ is Lipschitz in the sense that $\|p(x)-p(y)\|\leq d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in M$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $d$ is the distance determined by a Riemannian metric on $M$. Take any $\varepsilon>0$. Does there exist an idempotent $e\in M_n(C^\infty(M))$ that is $(1+\varepsilon)$-Lipschitz and such that $\|p(x)-e(x)\|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in M$?

I'd be grateful for any references that discuss this.

Comment: Is it not just a matter of using the density of smooth functions in local coordinates and then gluing over a [good cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_cover_(algebraic_topology)) by precompact charts?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine But how to ensure that $p^\infty$ is still a projection?

Comment: Instead of approximating a matrix valued function, you can approximate a projection valued function. Fixed rank projections form a smooth submanifold of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ (cf. [Stiefel manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold) for the case of orthogonal projections).

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I see. I guess this solves Q1 but perhaps not Q2 since it uses the norm on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: I don't know much about Riemannian manifolds, but I can answer the functional analysis side of your question. Suppose $f\colon M\to M_n^{\mathrm{s.a.}}$ is given such that $\|f(x)-p(x)\|<\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small. Then the projection-valued function $$e(x):=1_{(1-9\epsilon,1+9\epsilon)}(f(x))=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z-1|=1/2}\frac{dz}{z-f(x)}$$ satisfies $\|e(x)-p(x)\|<9\epsilon$ and is continuous/differentiable/etc whenever $f$ is. Moreover one can show $\mathrm{Lip}(e)\le(1+999\epsilon)\mathrm{Lip}(f)$. Perhaps, one can find an appropriate $f$ by a diffusion process?

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Hmm I only seem to be able to show $\text{Lip}(e)\leq 2\text{Lip}(f) + \delta$ for small $\delta$, by estimating $\rho(z-f)\geq\frac{1}{2}-\text{a bit}$. I wonder how this can be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I learned this was Rieffel's question and was already solved by Hanfeng Li. https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2994680

**Obsolete:**
The following is not an answer but maybe useful (see the comments above).

**Lemma.** Let $a,b$ be self-adjoint operators and $0<\epsilon<0.01$. Assume that $\|b-a\|<\epsilon$ and that the spectra of $a$ and $b$ are contained in the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $\{0,1\}$. Then the spectral projections satisfy $$\|1_{(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)}(b)-1_{(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)}(a)\|\le(1+999\epsilon)\|b-a\|.$$

**Proof.** Put $b(t):=a+t(b-a)$ and $p(t):=1_{(1-2\epsilon,1+2\epsilon)}(b(t))$.
By Cauchy's integral formula, one has
$$p(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\Gamma \frac{dz}{z-b(t)},$$
where $\Gamma:=\{|z-1|=\frac{1}{2}\}$. Take the derivative
$$p'(t)= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\Gamma (z-b(t))^{-1}b'(t)(z-b(t))^{-1}\,dz.$$
For $p:=p(0)$, one has $\|(z-b(t))^{-1}-(z-p)^{-1}\|<99\epsilon$ for $z\in\Gamma$,
because $\|(z-b(t))^{-1}\|<3$ and $\|b(t)-p\|\le\|b(t)-a\|+\|a-p\|<2\epsilon$.
Hence
\begin{align*}
p'(t) &\approx_{999\epsilon\|b-a\|}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\Gamma (z-p)^{-1}(b-a)(z-p)^{-1}\,dz\\
 &=p(b-a)p^\perp + p^\perp(b-a)p.
\end{align*}
Note that $\|p(b-a)p^\perp + p^\perp(b-a)p\|=\|p(b-a)p^\perp\|\le\|b-a\|$.
It follows that
$$\|p(1)-p(0)\|\le(1+999\epsilon)\|b-a\|.$$

Comment: I guess the $(b-1)$ in the second-last line should be $(b-a)$?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. By the way, the similar statement holds true for any unitarily invariant norm on $M_n$ other than the operator norm (but the proof gets a bit more complicated).